# Question on series of function (Multiple choice)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I was trying to solve he following two questions from a competitive exam paper. Both the questions are linked with following statement.

> Let $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{\{(n-1)x+1\}\{nx+1\}}$ and $s_n(x)=\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^nf_j(x)\forall x\in[0,1]$

First Question:

The sequence $\{s_n\}$

1. converges uniformly on $[0,1]$
2. converges pointwise on $[0,1]$ but not uniformly
3. converges pointwise for $x=0$ but not for $x\in(0,1]$
4. doesnot converge for $x\in [0,1]$

Second Question:

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1s_n(x)dx=1$ is obtained by

1. [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)
2. [Fatou's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma)
3. the fact that $\{s_n\}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$
4. the fact that $\{s_n\}$ converges pointwise on $[0,1]$

What I have done so far for the first question is that $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{\{(n-1)x+1\}}-\frac{1}{\{nx+1\}}$ which shows for a fixed $x$ $f_n(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ So I think pointwise convergence can be assured. But can I claim the pointwise convergence of $\{s_n\}$ from here?I am not sure about this.Also I have no idea about the uniform convergence.

and for  the second question I am completely stuck.I only know the statements of the two theorems given in the options.
Please help.

I admit that I don't have a great concept about convergence of sequence and series of functions and apologise for not showing much effort from my end.

Any help will be very helpful.Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decomposition

$$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{(n-1)x+1} - \frac{1}{nx+1}$$

shows that the sum telescopes,

$$s_n(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{nx+1}.\tag{1}$$

From that it is pretty easy to see how $(s_n)$ converges and to what. (Note: uniform convergence would imply continuity of the limit.)

$(1)$ shows that $(s_n)$ is uniformly bounded, so the dominated convergence theorem is one way to obtain the integral.

Comment: Thnx a lot.I missed that telescopic part.Can you please clarify the uniform convergence part of s_n?It will be very helpful then. Thnx again.

Comment: What is the pointwise limit? With the telescoping, that is easily found, and answers the question about uniform convergence.

Comment: The poinwise limit is 1.Am I correct?So s_n converges pointwise to 1.But is this convergence uniform?that I can't understand

Comment: The pointwise limit is not $1$ _everywhere_. There is an outsider.

Comment: So for x=0 limit is 0?

Comment: Yes. And that answers the question about uniform convergence.

Comment: How?Can you please explain?sorry.. sometimes I miss many easy things.May be here I am doing the same.

Comment: Since all $s_n$ are continuous, uniform convergence would imply continuity of the limit. The limit is not continuous at $0$, hence the convergence cannot be uniform.

Comment: I got it.It is clear now.Thanx a lot for giving your valuable time.Thank you.